# How to find formula for the given recurrence?

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

Given: $f(0)=0$ , $f(1)=1$   and a constant $n$
Recurrence : $f(i)=(2^{i}-1)^{n}-^iC_1f(i-1)-^iC_2f(i-2)-^iC_3f(i-3)...-^iC_if(i-i)$
Find formula of  $f(m)$ for some given $n$?
($^nC_k$ means number of ways choosing $k$ items from $n$ items)

Comment: I don't know what $C$ is.

Comment: Are $^iC_k$ binomial coefficients ?

Comment: Please provide additional context. Where are you stuck? Why can't you solve it yourself?

Comment: yes@ClaudeLeibovici and @stuart stevenson

Comment: @Václav Mordvinov I am not able to separate same coefficients terms and unable to simplify equation

Comment: @user8517664 Provide that context in the question itself. This way it looks like you ask others to do homework for you, instead you should show what you have tried and where you got stuck.